Which one of these is neither acidic or amphoteric? Would the same question be "which one is the most basic?" ? It says that b) is the answer
I'm stuck on this problem that isn't explained much in the teachers notes (no detailed explanation on why Bi2O3 is the answer).
Google gives mixed answers (it's either basic or amphoteric), and according to the teachers notes, amphoteric means that "the oxide possesses the same properties as acidic and basic oxides have"
How would I approach this problem? These are all elements in the same group, I would think that the nitrogen oxide could maybe stand out. But that is not the case here.

Which of the following oxides are neither considered to be acidic or amphoteric?


a)$\text{Sb}_2\text{O}_3$
b)$\text{Bi}_2\text{O}_3$
c)$\text{As}_2\text{O}_5$
d)$\text{N}_2\text{O}_3$
e)$\text{P}_4\text{O}_6$


As one goes down a column of the periodic table, element behavior becomes more metallic, i.e., more able to lose electrons (consider the shielding effect of inner shells).

$\ce{N2O3}$ is the "anhydride" of the unstable nitrous acid ($\ce{HNO2}$).
$\ce{P4O6}$ is formally the anhydride of phosphorous acid, $\ce{H3PO3}$.
$\ce{As2O5}$ is still acidic.
$\ce{Sb2O3}$ is amphoteric, reacting both with bases to form antimonites, and acids to form antimony salts.
$\ce{Bi2O3}$ is considered a basic oxide.


In the last columns of the periodic table, elements are forming oxides, which can form acids or hydroxides with water. In the same column, with the same oxidation number, elements from the first line are forming stronger acids than from the lowest lines. There is a continuous transition when going down the column. The weakest acid is obtained with the heaviest element. In the $15$th column, Bismuth is the heaviest stable element. This is why $\ce{Bi2O3}$ is the least acidic and the most basic oxide.
